# Regex that matches valid Ruby local variable names

Tags: ruby, regex, variables

Does anyone know the rules for valid Ruby variable names? Can it be matched using a RegEx?

**UPDATE:** This is what I could come up with so far:

```
^[_a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Does this seem right?

Comment: Yeah, that seems right.  I came up with about the same regexp.  Edit:  But you forgot the digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Identifiers are pretty straightforward.  They begin with letters or an underscore, and contain letters, underscore and numbers.  *Local* variables can't (or shouldn't?) begin with an uppercase letter, so you could just use a regex like this.

```
/^[a-z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$/
```

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Local variables cannot contain `?` or `!` to my knowledge.

Comment: The `+` should be a `*`, because `a` and `_` are valid variable names.

Comment: Yup: `!` and `?` are valid in method names but not in local vars AFAIK.

Comment: @Chuck: correct - `+` should be `*`. I am adding that to my regex. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think they are in Ruby, but I haven't tried that either.

Comment: Here it is: [Fun with Unicode](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/10/fun_with_unicode_1.html), though it uses examples of method names.

Comment: I see.  It can if you pass -Ku to switch to unicode encoding.

Comment: @AboutRuby, no more `-Ku` magick since 1.9. All works fine with unicode cyrillic variables.

Comment: [`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is also known as `\w`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible for variable names to be unicode letters, in which case most of the existing regexes don't match.

```
varname = "\u2211" # => "∑" 
eval(varname + '= "Tony the Pony"') => "Tony the Pony"
puts varname # => ∑
local_variable_identifier = /Insert large regular expression here/
varname =~ local_variable_identifier # => nil
```

See also "Fun with Unicode" in either the Ruby 1.9 Pickaxe or at [Fun with Unicode](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/10/fun_with_unicode_1.html).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. However my goal is to make sure an user input matches a variable name, so I am fine with a safe subset of the actual naming rules.

Comment: @kolrie, in that case, just use the regx `^a+$`. It's safe to have a variable named any number of "a"s.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html a Ruby variable consists of:

> A name is an uppercase letter,
>   lowercase letter, or an underscore
>   ("_"), followed by Name characters
>   (this is any combination of upper- and
>   lowercase letters, underscore and
>   digits).

In addition, global variables begin with a dollar sign, instance variables with a single at-sign, and class variables with two at-signs.

A regular expression to match all that would be:

```
%r{
  (\$|@{1,2})?  # optional leading punctuation
  [A-Za-z_]     # at least one upper case, lower case, or underscore
  [A-Za-z0-9_]* # optional characters (including digits)
}x
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am accepting the first one, because I am looking for local variables only (no names, ivars or classvars).

Answer (score 3):

I like @aboutruby's answer, but just to complete it, here's the equivalent using [POSIX bracket expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

```
/^[_[:lower:]][_[:alnum:]]*$/
```

Or, since `a-z` is actually shorter than `[:lower:]`:

```
/^[_a-z][_[:alnum:]]*$/
```

Comment: +1 for the first variant, since it can handle letters other than a-z.

Answer (score 1):

I think `/^(\$){0,1}[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*([?!]){0,1}$/` is a bit closer to what you will need...

It depends on whether you want to match method names as well.

If you are trying to match a name that might be encountered in an expression, then it might start with $ and it might end with ? or !. If you know for sure that it is just a local variable then the rule will be much simpler.

Comment: Local variables cannot begin with $, and matching 0 or 1 $'s is easier said as \$?.  The same with [?!]? instead of ([?!]){0,1}, and variable names can't end in them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

i was trying to figure one out for a rails patch, and Matthew Draper [wrote this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26672#discussion_r81426773), using the [ruby parser](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/46bbb62bed20e93b651a9f19c87634d2732f05a5/parse.y#L5184) as a reference:

```
/\A(?![A-Z0-9])(?:[[:alnum:]_]|[^\0-\177])+\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

And here it is, straight from the horse's mouth. (The horse in this case is the [Draft ISO Ruby Specification](http://Ruby-Std.NetLab.Jp/)):

- **local-variable-identifier** → `(` **lowercase-character** `|` <kbd>_</kbd> `)` **identifier-character** `*`
- **identifier-character** → **lowercase-character** `|` **uppercase-character** `|` **decimal-digit** `|` <kbd>_</kbd>
- **uppercase-character** → <kbd>A</kbd> `|` <kbd>B</kbd> `|` <kbd>C</kbd> `|` <kbd>D</kbd> `|` <kbd>E</kbd> `|` <kbd>F</kbd> `|` <kbd>G</kbd> `|` <kbd>H</kbd> `|` <kbd>I</kbd> `|` <kbd>J</kbd> `|` <kbd>K</kbd> `|` <kbd>L</kbd> `|` <kbd>M</kbd> `|` <kbd>N</kbd> `|` <kbd>O</kbd> `|` <kbd>P</kbd> `|` <kbd>Q</kbd> `|` <kbd>R</kbd> `|` <kbd>S</kbd> `|` <kbd>T</kbd> `|` <kbd>U</kbd> `|` <kbd>V</kbd> `|` <kbd>W</kbd> `|` <kbd>X</kbd> `|` <kbd>Y</kbd> `|` <kbd>Z</kbd>
- **lowercase-character** → <kbd>a</kbd> `|` <kbd>b</kbd> `|` <kbd>c</kbd> `|` <kbd>d</kbd> `|` <kbd>e</kbd> `|` <kbd>f</kbd> `|` <kbd>g</kbd> `|` <kbd>h</kbd> `|` <kbd>i</kbd> `|` <kbd>j</kbd> `|` <kbd>k</kbd> `|` <kbd>l</kbd> `|` <kbd>m</kbd> `|` <kbd>n</kbd> `|` <kbd>o</kbd> `|` <kbd>p</kbd> `|` <kbd>q</kbd> `|` <kbd>r</kbd> `|` <kbd>s</kbd> `|` <kbd>t</kbd> `|` <kbd>u</kbd> `|` <kbd>v</kbd> `|` <kbd>w</kbd> `|` <kbd>x</kbd> `|` <kbd>y</kbd> `|` <kbd>z</kbd>
- **decimal-digit** → <kbd>0</kbd> `|` <kbd>1</kbd> `|` <kbd>2</kbd> `|` <kbd>3</kbd> `|` <kbd>4</kbd> `|` <kbd>5</kbd> `|` <kbd>6</kbd> `|` <kbd>7</kbd> `|` <kbd>8</kbd> `|` <kbd>9</kbd>

In Ruby 1.9, using named groups, you can translate this literally:

```
local_variable_identifier = %r{ 
  (?<uppercase_character>     A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M
                            | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z
  ){0} 
  (?<lowercase_character>     a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m
                            | n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y | z
  ){0} 
  (?<decimal_digit>         0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9){0} 
  (?<identifier_character>    \g<lowercase_character>
                            | \g<uppercase_character>
                            | \g<decimal_digit>
                            | _
  ){0} 

  ( \g<lowercase_character> | _ ) \g<identifier_character>*
}x
```

Of course, this is not how you would really write it.