# What is the regular expression to find "$name" from "abc $name,efg" in Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, regex

Let me ask what  is the regular expression to find  "$name" from "abc $name,defg" in Ruby code?
For details ,

```
"$name" must follow the Ruby syntax for global variable names;
I distinguish "$name" from the including text just by "$" at the head 
and a non allowed character for variable names after the tail.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex that matches valid Ruby local variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648551/regex-that-matches-valid-ruby-local-variable-names)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think the remaining question is how to find the head "$".

Comment: Um, put a literal "$" in your regex? I realize SO is convenient, but I highly recommend learning some regex basics.

Comment: Yes I agree , I need to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `match()` on your regex.
    `/\$name/.m­atch(*yourString*)`