# RegEx matching variable names but not string values

Tags: regex, variables, identifier

It is hard to find. I need to write lexer and tokenizer for it. 
I've got a problem in finding a regex which matches variable names but not string values.

The following *should not* be matched:

```
"ala ma kota"
5aalaas
```

This *should* be matched:

```
ala_ma_KOTA999653
l90
a
```

I already got something like this:

```
[a-zA-z]\w+
```

but I don't know how to exclude `"` chars from the beginning and end of a match.

Thanks for any reply or google links (I couldn't find it - it can be from lmgify ;)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex that matches valid Ruby local variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648551/regex-that-matches-valid-ruby-local-variable-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret variable names as all word character sequences with a min length of 1 and starting with a letter. Your regexp was almost correct then:

```
^[A-Za-z]\w*$
```